# Python + Sheet | May I know the syntax to change BGcolor using BatchUpdate?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, background-color, batch-updates

The following python code is a BatchUpdate that:

1. Add a number 'x' to Column H of row
2. Change the whole row to green

There can be 1 or many rows involved.
How do I change the background color?
Also, if rowListTH[] only has 1 item, will this code still work?

```
ssName = ssTH.title + '!'
request_body = {
    "valueInputOption": "RAW",
    "data": [
        {
            'range': ssName + 'H'+rowListTH[-1]+':H'+rowListTH[0],
            'values': [
                {
                    [str(x)],
                    "backgroundColor": {"green": 1}
                }
                ]
        },
    ]
}
service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(
    spreadsheetId = ssID,
    body = request_body
).execute()
```

================================== EDIT ==================================

I have made the changes, but I could not get the update to color the entire row or column, it will always color only a single cell.
Please check where do I do wrongly

I want to color rows 5-12 column A to I.
For my result, I only get cell A5 colored.

```
request_body = {
"updateCells":{
    "rows":[
        {
            "values":[
                {
                    "userEnteredFormat":{
                        "backgroundColor":{
                            "red": 0,
                            "green": 1,
                            "blue": 0,
                            "alpha": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
            ],
            "fields":"userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor",
            "range":{
                "sheetId": TH_gid,
                "startRowIndex": 4,
                "endRowIndex": 11,
                "startColumnIndex": 0,
                "endColumnIndex": 9
            }
        }
    }
body = {
    "requests": request_body
}
response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=ssID, body=body).execute()
```

[image: BGcolor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*To change the background colour of a cell you need to use the `spreadsheets.batchUpdate` endpoint, not the `spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate` endpoint.*

#### Example request:

```py
request_body = {
    "updateCells":{
        "rows":[
            {
                "values":[
                    {
                        "userEnteredFormat":{
                            "backgroundColor":{
                                "red": 0,
                                "green": 1,
                                "blue": 0,
                                "alpha": 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "fields":"userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor",
        "range":{
            "sheetId": sheet-id,
            "startRowIndex": 0,
            "endRowIndex": 0,
            "startColumnIndex": 0,
            "endColumnIndex": 1
        }
    }
}

body = {
    "requests": request_body
}

response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=ss.id, body=body).execute()
```

**Things you will need to change:**

- The `red`, `green`, `blue` and `alpha` values. [As per the documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#Color), these are floating point representations between 0 and 1 of the RGB colourspace with a denominator of 255.

  - For example, for white, which is `#FFFFFF` or `255 255 255` you would use  for each of `red`, `green` and `blue`.
- The Sheet ID - this is NOT the spreadsheet ID, this is the `#gid` which is seen in the URL when you view the Spreadsheet in a browser. `Sheet1` by default is always `0`, but any added sheets are random. This value is an integer.
- The start and end column and rows:

  - `startRowIndex`, `endRowIndex`, `startColumnIndex` and `endColumnIndex` are 0-indexed. This means that if you want to colour only cell `A1`, then your request would be:

```
"startRowIndex": 0,
"endRowIndex": 1,
"startColumnIndex": 0,
"endColumnIndex": 1
```

To colour an entire column, you would first need to find out the number of rows and make the following request (assumiung column A):

```
"startRowIndex": 0,
"endRowIndex": number_of_rows - 1,
"startColumnIndex": 0,
"endColumnIndex": 1
```

As this is a different endpoing than the one you have used, this will need to be made as a separate HTTP request.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [Requests - `UpdateCellsRequest` | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)
- [Cells - `CellFormat` | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellFormat)
- [Other - `GridRange` | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange)
- [Other - `Color` | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#Color)

Comment: May I know if this is only to change BgColor? If I also want to change cell values? Add a number 'x' to Column H of row

Comment: @user2741620 You can't - the endpoints to update background colours and values are different and you need to make two requests. `spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate()` can be used for values only, whereas other call settings have to be done with a structural change, using `spreadsheets.batchUpdate()`.

Comment: I see. Alright, I will do a separate write request. Thanks

Comment: I have made the changes but cannot get the result as intended. Could you help to see what is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by `cannot get the result as intended`? What is happening instead?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my original post and added an image. Hope it's clearer now.